# Smooth way to set all other togglebuttons to unchecked when one is checked

Tags: android

I specifically didn't want to use a radiogroup. I know, I know ... a radiogroup is perfect when you need exclusivity like this.

But..given that I'm working with togglebuttons, how can i disable (setChecked(false)) all (3) other toggle buttons when one of them is checked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'll need to implement your own radiogroup logic for that. It will need to register itself as the OnCheckedChangeListener for each button it manages.

I wish the API wasn't designed with RadioGroup as a LinearLayout. It would have been much better to separate the radio group management from layout.

Comment: Yea, well said about the LinearLayout issue. I can't keep exlusivity of radiogroup when I want to use neither vertical or horizontonal orientation. I want the radiogroup to be in a "square", but can't do it. Can you show me an example of how to implement such logic and registering the oncheckedchangelistener for each button?

Answer (score 4):

Here is my code for the group of toggle buttons. You need to put your 
buttons in the layout where you want them and then use ToggleButtonsGroup object to put them together in a single group.

```
private class ToggleButtonsGroup implements OnCheckedChangeListener {

    private ArrayList<ToggleButton> mButtons;

    public ToggleButtonsGroup() {

        mButtons = new ArrayList<ToggleButton>();

    }

    public void addButton(ToggleButton btn) {

        btn.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);

        mButtons.add(btn);
    }

    public ToggleButton getSelectedButton() {

        for(ToggleButton b : mButtons) {
            if(b.isChecked())
                return b;
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
            boolean isChecked) {

        if(isChecked) {
            uncheckOtherButtons(buttonView.getId());

            mDataChanged = true;

        } else if (!anyButtonChecked()){
            buttonView.setChecked(true);
        }

    }

    private boolean anyButtonChecked() {

        for(ToggleButton b : mButtons) {
            if(b.isChecked())
                return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    private void uncheckOtherButtons(int current_button_id) {

        for(ToggleButton b : mButtons) {                
            if(b.getId() != current_button_id)
                b.setChecked(false);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Well done. The only thing I would change would be to avoid using button ids in `uncheckOtherButtons`. Just compare buttons using `==`.

Answer (score 0):

I know this has been answered with very good examples, but the way I set mine up is just a tad different so I thought I'd share. It's on a preference list, no ToggleButtonsGroup involved.

```
@Override
    public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {
        String key = preference.getKey();
        if (key.equals("trailPref") || key.equals("obstaclesPref") || key.equals("insanePref") || key.equals("backgroundBlackPref"))
        {
            if (key.equals("insanePref"))
            {
                endurancebox.setChecked(false);
                prefsEditor.putBoolean("obstaclesPref", false);
                prefsEditor.commit();
            }

            if (key.equals("obstaclesPref"))
            {
                insanebox.setChecked(false);
                prefsEditor.putBoolean("insanePref", false);
                prefsEditor.commit();
            }


            boolean b = ((CheckBoxPreference) preference).isChecked();
            prefsEditor.putBoolean(key, b);
            prefsEditor.commit();
        }

        Log.i(DEBUG_TAG, "Boolean value changed. " + key );
        returnPrefs(c);
        return false;
    }
```

Also, I'm an Android noob and not too experienced in java either, so it may not be uber efficient, but hey, it works! Could be formatted easily to fit your needs I believe. If the key equals insanePref, I want to turn off obstaclesPref and vice versa. (different game modes, only one can be active at the time.) The other two booleans are unrelated. Also, it puts the preferences into my SharedPreference file, instantiated earlier, along with everything else.

Cheers!